# Is there a name for the type of word that the word, “scarecrow,” is? (a transitive verb conjoined with its object)

Tags: etymology, verbs, nouns, transitivity

The English word, “scarecrow,” spontaneously came to mind the other day, and I realized just how similar this word is to other words and phrases in other languages.

For example, there are many commonly used nouns in Spanish that are formed by conjoining a transitive verb with its object (with the verb preceding the object, just like in the word, “scarecrow”) (e.g. “trabalengua” (lit. “twist tongue”) means “tongue twister,” and “lavaplato” (lit. “wash plate”) means “dishwasher”). In Chinese, there may be entire phrases and sentences which may be perceived to be verb phrases (especially within the framework of English or Western grammar), when they are actually meant to be perceived as “states”/“events”/“nouns” (not principally being some form of action).

I was wondering if there is a name for this kind of construction. This kind of construction seems rare in English - am I right? So far, I have only been able to think of “scarecrow.”

**EDIT:**

After some thought, the comparison I made between "scarecrow" and entire Chinese sentences/phrases is not a fair one. It seems like I was conflating exocentric compounds and endocentric compounds.

Consider, for example, the Chinese dictionary entry, “大爷 : 尊称年长的男子” (word by word, this phrase translates to: “大爷 (Sir) : 尊称 (respectfully-address) 年长的男子 (elder-gentleman)”). A proper direct translation for this dictionary entry would be: “Sir: respectfully address an elder gentleman.” Granted, what the word, “大爷,” represents is not some kind of action that can be expressed via a verb phrase, but rather a form of address. Therefore, a more natural translation for this dictionary entry would be: “Sir: a respectful address towards an elder gentleman.”

Now, let’s analyze “scarecrow.” “Scarecrow” is comprised of the verb, “scare,” and the object, “crow,” both separate words of which, when put together, can make up the verb phrase, “scare (a) crow.” The verb phrase in the direct English translation of the Chinese dictionary above can be, for our purposes, be reduced to “respectfully-address-(a)-gentleman” (“尊称男子”); this verb phrase contains the verb phrase, “respectfully-address,” and the object, “gentleman.” Unlike the word, “scarecrow,” the phrase, “respectfully-address-(a)-gentleman,” (which, in Chinese, may be considered to act as a single unit) does not refer to the perpetrator of the action, but rather the verbal noun (“address”) that relates to the action (“addressing”). In this context, wouldn’t we be able to say that this phrase mimics an endocentric compound? It seems like we could say that “respectfully-address-(a)-gentleman” is a noun that inherits the constituent, “address,” or “respectfully-address.”

As a matter of fact, endocentric compounds seem to be abundant in Chinese not only in the form of longer phrases and sentences, but also in the form of shorter phrases or words. For example: “煮鸡蛋” (lit. “boil egg”) means, “boiled egg.” (from the Chinese dictionaries I’ve used, the character/word, “煮” (“boil”), is NOT assigned any part of speech that is not “verb”)

Perhaps, earlier, I was conflating exocentric compounds and endocentric compounds (and thus made the comparison between “scarecrow” and endocentric compounds in Chinese).

Comment: This type of compound was very common in Old English.  The dictionary is full of them.  Some modern words are old compounds in disguise:  LORD < HLAF-ORD = LOAF WARD.  We still employ compound generation for vocabulary expansion, but we leave spaces between the words.

Comment: @BertBarrois "loaf ward" is a more standard English compound. It would be like "scarecrow" if it were "ward-loaf".

Comment: Tangentially, [here's an article](https://doi.org/10.1017/S1366728999000346) that simply compares "left-headed" and "right-headed" compounds, including ones like "scarecrow", in the context of bilingual acquisition — the title refers to French children applying their language's typical structure to generate the unlikely English "*brushteeth" for "toothbrush". :)

Comment: @BertBarrois _Lord_ is a completely different kettle of fish. It’s a standard endocentric compound consisting of two nouns, the latter governing the former: a loaf ward is a ward (= warden, guardian) of loaves. There is no verbal element in _lord_ like there is in _scarecrow_. It’s semantically similar to the _truckdriver_ type (object + verb-derived agent), but not morphologically, since a ward(en) isn’t a verb-derived agent, just a noun that happens to have a corresponding (identical) verb.

Comment: German is known for its many compounds (dare I say, a compound-lust), although most of them are of a different kind than this one. Indeed, the German equivalent of scarecrow, "Vogelscheuche" (bird-shoo) works similarly but has the order reversed and "Scheuche" is a noun (not a verb), to make it match the standard German order that the last part of the compound gives the generic part and the first part specifies it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet There's another word for the sort of combination that produces "Lord": a *Portmanteau*.  The difference here is you only take parts of the original 2 words rather than the whole thing, so e.g. "**Br**eakfast" + "L**unch**" = "**Brunch**".

Comment: @DarrelHoffman ‘Lord’ isn’t a portmanteau, though, since it’s not based on the first part of one word being glued together with the last part of another – it’s just a regular compound of two whole words. The fact that it looks a bit like a portmanteau now is pure coincidence, due to the fact that the /vw/ in the middle of the word was lost over time. ‘Portmanteau’ itself, however, **is** an example of a (French) pickpocket/cutthroat/tosspot compound, a ‘carry-mantle’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yeah, this construction is more common in French I think, often hyphenated e.g. "pince-nez", "amuse-bouche", for a couple more examples that are borrowed in English.

Comment: Why have you analyzed "scare-" as a verb and not a noun?

Answer (score 14):

This is a specific subtype of [exocentric compound](https://www.thoughtco.com/exocentric-compound-words-1690583). An exocentric compound is one which doesn't inherit the type of either of its constituents: a *scarecrow* is neither a type of crow nor a type of scaring. (The opposite is an endocentric compound, which does: e.g. a *blackbird* is a type of bird.)

There are many types of exocentric compound, and AFAIK there isn't a single standard name in use for this particular subtype. It's sometimes simply called an "exocentric verb-noun compound", for obvious reasons. Within Indo-European studies specifically, the terms "terpsimbrotos compound" and
"phereoikos compound" are sometimes used, based on specific Greek examples of the type, but these aren't very common. At least one researcher who works on these compounds in English calls them "[cutthroat compounds](https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2015/04/28/cutthroat-compounds-in-english-morphology/)". There are actually several hundred of these in English, but most are rare or obsolete. In the Romance languages they're a productive type, as you imply.

Comment: Interestingly, "cutthroat" is itself a cutthroat compound. I imagine this was deliberate on her part.

Comment: @Barmar Yes indeed... not much other reason to coin the term :)

Answer (score 8):

There are actually several of these words in English: "rattlesnake", "crybaby", "scatterbrain", "killjoy", "tattletale", "tumbleweed", etc. They are sometimes called "flat compounds". Notably, some of them combine a verb with its *object* (a "turncoat" is a person who turns their coat), while others combine a verb with its *subject* (a "turntable" is a table that turns records).

[Ljiljana Progovac](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2016.01714/full) suggests that these "flat compounds" are possible in *all* (or at least a good majority of) languages, and cites a variety of examples: Serbian *cepi-dlaka* "split-hair", Twi *kukru-bin* "roll-dung" (type of beetle), Polish *moczy-morda* "soak-muzzle" (drunkard), Ukrainian *lomi-golovka* "break-head" (puzzle), Russian *verti-hvostka* "spin-tail" (flirt), Italian *faci-male* "do-evil", Berber *ssum-sitan* "suck-cow" (insect), etc. In addition, across languages, when these words are applied to humans they are generally insulting or derogatory. (Some of these examples are taken from the linked article; others come from her book *Evolutionary Syntax*, which is not freely available.)

She dubs this a "two-slot grammar"—a non-recursive way of combining a noun with a verb—and proposes that it could have been the ancestor of modern recursive syntax, as a next step up from just giving names to things. The next step up from *there* is combining two of these "two-slot" structures: "monkey see monkey do", "first come first serve", "like father like son" (Twi *wo dua wo twa* "you sow you reap", Hmong *cua daj cua dub* "wind yellow wind black" meaning "storm"), and from there it's a short step to full recursive syntax.

In other words, according to Progovac, these "flat compounds" are a relic of an earlier stage in the evolution in syntax. They may be a true universal found in every language (much like many linguists say recursive syntax is).

EDIT: Sorry, I misunderstood what exactly you were asking about. The specific type you're talking about (with an object rather than a subject) are *exocentric* compounds, as opposed to *endocentric* compounds incorporating the subject. Progovac claims that the two should be analyzed similarly, but many other linguists disagree. If you're talking specifically about exocentric compounds, "killjoy", "tattletail", and "turncoat" qualify, while "crybaby", "tumbleweed", and "turntable" do not.

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between the ones that include the object (exocentric) and the ones that include the subject (endocentric). Very often, only one type is really used productively, and unlike Germanic languages where that’s the endocentric type, it is typologically most common that it’s the exocentric type (as also indicated by the fact that all the examples you cite from Progovac are exocentric). Romance and Slavic languages, for instance, hardly know the endocentric type at all.

Comment: No such word as  lomi-golovka ("ломи-головка"? there is "головоломка", but no verb here) in Russian; need a better example  (probably "Перекати-поле"?).

Esperanto example can be "partopreni".

Comment: "scarecrow" is very different from "rattlesnake"!

Comment: @LukeSawczak Right, "rattlesnake" seems short for "rattling snake" or "snake with a rattle".

Comment: @Barmer "rattlesnake" looks like German "Klapperschlange", where "klapper" is the inflexive verb form.

Comment: @MarkKahn Hm, interesting. I'll admit I don't speak much Russian so I just took all the examples straight from the source (she cites Pugach et al 2006). Others on her list include perekati-pole as you mentioned, but also verti-hvostka and sorvi-golova; do those sound more natural?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Progovac focuses mainly on the exocentric ones (like OP's "scarecrow"), but claims that the two constructions are very similar in their usage (e.g. primarily being derogatory when applied to humans) and should be analyzed as coming from the same origin.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Indeed, "rattlesnake" could also come from the noun, but Progovac analyzes it as coming from the verb (a snake that rattles), much like "tumbleweed" being a weed that tumbles. (In which case it's still endocentric rather than exocentric, but see the comment above.)

Comment: @Draconis The two Russian examples I know (or maybe they’re OCS? Can’t remember now) because they’re always the ones used for Slavic, are _Vladimir_ and _verti-golova_, which looks like a hybrid between the ones you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: *ломиголовка* is Ukrainian, not Russian. In Ukraine and Russia there are lots of surnames which are formed according to this pattern: *Вертипорох* "tumble-powder", *Непейпиво* "do-not-drink-beer", *Убейволк* "kill-wolf" etc., formed by conjoining a verb in imperative and its subject.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet why hybrid? For me they are clearly verb + subject (although власти uses instrumental or dative). BTW, many such surnames or nicknames also in Czech.

Comment: @VladimirF Hybrid because the two examples he’d given included _verti-_ and _-golova_, but not together.

Comment: I see... I thought you mean the gramar types. Reminds me vrtichvost and třasořitka (wagtail), both literally very similar (moving the rear part or the tail), but figuratively very different (bootlicker=patolízal vs. scrag, fearful person).

Comment: My question edit was only an amendment discussing endocentric compounds in Chinese. My original question was referring to exocentric compounds to begin with.

Comment: @dry_apricot_09 Indeed; I think I just misunderstood you, and that's my bad.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: the *-мир* in *Владимир* is folk etymology. It comes from Proto-Slavic _*Voldiměrъ_ (not _**Voldimirъ_). In this reading it's not the kind of construct the OP is asking about.

Comment: @Quassnoi Etymologically, you’re right, of course; but in contemporary Russian, it functions as a pickpocket compound, regardless of the fact that it’s a folk etymology (if you can even call it that – it’s just a misanalysis by native speakers, which happens all the time).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I thought word formation through misanalysis by speakers was the definition of the folk etymology, no? Like "cockroach" or "woodchuck". BTW, _вертиголова_ is not a thing in Russian or Church Slavonic either, it's a Ukrainian word. Russian has _вертиголовка_ (a bird species).

Comment: @Quassnoi Hm, seems you’re right. I’d always thought of folk etymology as being specifically about _etymology_ – that is, about the origins of a word (such as the ‘fornication under consent of the king’ and ‘port out, starboard home’ type), rather than simple analogical replacement of unfamiliar forms by familiar ones, but my distinction doesn’t seem to be reflected in standard definitions.

Comment: @Draconis: Yes, verti-hvostka and sorvi-golova (вертихвостка and сорвиголова) are good examples.

Answer (score 2):

A [comment to Anu Garg's A-Word-A-Day](http://wordsmith.org/awad/awadmail592.html) suggested that these might be known as **'tosspot' words**, which has become a recurring [theme](http://www.wordsmith.org/words/shunpike.html) on AWAD. The term is [slowly](http://csperryess.blogspot.com/2013/11/tosspot-words.html) [spreading](https://sophia.smith.edu/blog/wordinyourear/2016/02/19/tosspot/) to [blogs](https://www.perryess.com/blog/tosspot-words), but I don't know if it's made it into any 'serious' publications.

Comment: _Pickpocket compounds_ is what I’ve mostly heard, but that too is not a standardised term by any means, just a random example someone used at some point and now some more people use it here and there.

Comment: A tosspot is a type of pot. A scarecrow is not a type of crow. The OP is asking about verbs conjoined with their *object*. Pickpocket would indeed be a better example!

Comment: @JamesMartin A tosspot is a person, not a pot. It’s someone who tosses [= drinks] their pot [of ale].

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks Janus and apologies Aakash! I was under a complete misapprehension there! At least I've learnt something this morning. Following this through Wiktionary even led me to the rarer "squeeze-grape" which I enjoyed.